# JTextArea setFont changes the size of the textarea

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a `JTextArea` at a set size, but if i change the font of the area, the size of the area changes as well.

```
    textArea = new JTextArea(20,40);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setFont(font);
```

I know this because of the size of the row and column count changes with the font size. but if I comment out the `setFont`, and I add a JButton with an `ActionListener` that calls the exact same thing, the `JTextArea` stays the same

```
    if(e.getSource() == applyButton){
        textArea.setFont(fc.getSelectedFont());
    }
```

the `font` and `fc.getSelectedFont` are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every change within the ***layout*** of any swing component, won't take effect until `revalidate()` is called. `repaint()` does not help in that case.

In your first case, you made the change *before* it was visible on the screen. When first made visible, Swing calls `revalidate()` for you. Your second case is different at this!.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the textarea the same size no matter what? because this works as it is, but if i start changing the size of the jframe it repaints again and remakes the size of the textArea